# Setting Default In Array For Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox

So am having a problem with setting defaults for a checkbox setup in a form
at the top of the php file I have the following code:

```
       <?php
 if (is_array("check_list") && in_array("1",$_POST["check_list"]))
    {
      $checked = "";
    }
    else 
    {
     $checked = "checked";
    }
    if (is_array("check_list") && in_array("2",$_POST["check_list"]))
    {
      $checked = "";
    }
    else 
    {
     $checked = "checked";
    }
?>
```

In the body of the page there is a form that calls the same page and I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1" <?php echo $checked; ?> style="margin-left:18px;"> Option 1 <input type="checkbox"  name="check_list[]" value="2" <?php echo $checked; ?> style="margin-left:18px;"> Option 2
```

And then further down the page and based on the selection above:

```
                <?php if (is_array("check_list") && in_array("1",$_POST["check_list"])){ ?> 
                 <li data-link="option1"><a>Option 1</a></li>
                <?php } ?>

                 <?php if (is_array("check_list") && in_array("2",$_POST["check_list"])){ ?>                     
                <li data-link="Option2"><a>Option 2</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
```

What I want to achieve is that the checkboxes are all selected as default
when the page first loads and then if subsequently unchecked it remembers 
the state and shows as unchecked when another search is performed.

The above is the result of different attempts to get it working right - have searched and have arrived at this but it is ugly and can probably be written 
much better in less lines.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: `is_array("check_list")` is always going to return false (`"check_list"` is a string).

Comment: ah ok - what should it be then please?

Answer (score 1):

Check `!isset($_POST)` to determine if a form has been sent as POST, if not then default, otherwise check for the value in the `$_POST['check_list']` array:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST) || (is_array($_POST["check_list"]) && in_array(1, $_POST["check_list"]))){ ?> 
  <li data-link="option1"><a>Option 1</a></li>
<?php } ?>

// Assume these are $_POST, which is what you would use.
// Comment both out for default, no form posted.
// Uncomment one or both to try different combos.
//$post = array('check_list' => array(2,4));
//$post = array('check_list' => array(3,4,6,9));

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $checked = '';

    if (!isset($post)
         || (is_array($post['check_list'])
              && in_array($i, $post['check_list']))) {
        $checked = " checked='true'";
    }

    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$i' value='$i'$checked/> $i" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Commented out (simulates default, not form posted):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='0' value='0' checked='true'/> 0
<input type='checkbox' name='1' value='1' checked='true'/> 1
<input type='checkbox' name='2' value='2' checked='true'/> 2
<input type='checkbox' name='3' value='3' checked='true'/> 3
<input type='checkbox' name='4' value='4' checked='true'/> 4
<input type='checkbox' name='5' value='5' checked='true'/> 5
<input type='checkbox' name='6' value='6' checked='true'/> 6
<input type='checkbox' name='7' value='7' checked='true'/> 7
<input type='checkbox' name='8' value='8' checked='true'/> 8
<input type='checkbox' name='9' value='9' checked='true'/> 9
```

First `$post`:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='0' value='0'/> 0
<input type='checkbox' name='1' value='1'/> 1
<input type='checkbox' name='2' value='2' checked='true'/> 2
<input type='checkbox' name='3' value='3'/> 3
<input type='checkbox' name='4' value='4' checked='true'/> 4
<input type='checkbox' name='5' value='5'/> 5
<input type='checkbox' name='6' value='6'/> 6
<input type='checkbox' name='7' value='7'/> 7
<input type='checkbox' name='8' value='8'/> 8
<input type='checkbox' name='9' value='9'/> 9
```

Second `$post`:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='0' value='0'/> 0
<input type='checkbox' name='1' value='1'/> 1
<input type='checkbox' name='2' value='2'/> 2
<input type='checkbox' name='3' value='3' checked='true'/> 3
<input type='checkbox' name='4' value='4' checked='true'/> 4
<input type='checkbox' name='5' value='5'/> 5
<input type='checkbox' name='6' value='6' checked='true'/> 6
<input type='checkbox' name='7' value='7'/> 7
<input type='checkbox' name='8' value='8'/> 8
<input type='checkbox' name='9' value='9' checked='true'/> 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant

```
if (is_array($_POST["check_list"]) && in_array("1",$_POST["check_list"]))
```

You are also using one variable `$checked` to try to hold both the checked-state of option 1 and option 2.  Try having 2 variables `$checked1` and `$checked2`. The way it is now, whatever you would have set `$checked` to while seeing if Option 1 was checked will get overwritten with whatever Option 2 is.